files.upload API method being deprecated for uploading test results to Slack via Selenium WebDriver 4.0
I'm using Selenium WebDriver 4.19 with Java and I upload my test results to Slack. Slack notified me the other day that the files.upload web API method I use to do that is being deprecated.
Updates required for apps still using the files.upload API 

A workspace that you administer contains apps or integrations that recently used the files.upload web API method. We want to inform you about two important changes coming to support for the files.upload API.
 
May 8, 2024 
Newly created Slack apps will no longer be able to access the files.upload API. Existing applications will be able to continue using files.upload until support is discontinued. 
 
March 11, 2025 
Support for the files.upload API for all apps will be discontinued. 

To prepare for this change, we recommend that app owners migrate away from files.upload and instead use the combination of files.getUploadURLExternal(https://api.slack.com/methods/files.getUploadURLExternal) and files.completeUploadExternal(https://api.slack.com/methods/files.getUploadURLExternal). You can also leverage Slack's SDKs to help transition to this new way of uploading files by visiting our api.slack page(https://api.slack.com/messaging/files#uploading_files). 

According to the api.slack page, these are the instructions to solve the problem

Call files.getUploadURLExternal. The response will contain a URL that you can POST the contents of your file to.
POST the contents of your file to the URL returned in step 1. This can be done by sending the raw bytes, or can be a multipart form ended request. If all went well, Slack will respond with an HTTP 200.
Call files.completeUploadExternal. You can optionally specify a sharing destination for your file or files using this API's arguments. This finalizes the file upload started in step 1.

Here is the existing code that I use with files.upload. The code takes care of posting the contents to Java.  I'm new/very green to Java. I don't understand what they mean by Call files.getUploadURLExternal and Call files.completeUploadExternal. Does anybody have sample Java code which explains how these call statements work.
// This method sends the test execution results report to Slack
public void sendTestExecutionReportToSlack() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://slack.com/api/files.upload"; // This is the Slack url to upload the test execution results report to

    try {
        // This is the code to send the test execution report to Slack
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableContentCompression().build(); // Initiate the HttpClient to send the test execution results report to
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); // Post the Slack url
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create(); // Build the builder entity to host the test execution results report
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(PathToReport)); // Add the path of the test execution results report to the file body
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); // Set up the builder structure to send the test execution results report and make sure it is browser compatible
        builder.addPart("file", fileBody); // Add the file containing the test execution results report to the builder structure
        builder.addTextBody("channels", channelName); // Add the channelName to the builder TextBody
        builder.addTextBody("token", botUserOAuthAccessToken); // Add the token to the builder TextBody
        httppost.setEntity(builder.build()); // Set the Entity for builder, post the test execution results report with all the builder components including file, channels and token
        HttpResponse response = null; // Set the HTTPResponse to null
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // The response is equal to the result of httppost
        HttpEntity result = response.getEntity(); // HTTPEntity Result equals the response of getEntity

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If the code to send the test execution results report fails, print the associated stack trace
        e.printStackTrace(); // Print the Stack Trace
    }
}

Also, https://api.slack.com/methods/files.getUploadURLExternal requires a mandatory integer/length argument (Size in bytes of the file being uploaded.) Can that be accomplished with builder.addPart()

This has nothing to do with Selenium so I removed that tag and added [java].

Did you look at the docs? It has sample code... https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

This seemed to work
PathToReport = path+"//ExtentReports//"+ClsName+DateStmp+".html"; //This is the path to the test results report            

rep = new File(PathToReport); //File Object created for the test report

namefile = rep.getName(); //The name of the file for the test report
        
Slack slack = Slack.getInstance(); //Start an instance of Slack
        
FilesUploadV2Request.UploadFile v2UploadFile = FilesUploadV2Request.UploadFile.builder()  //Start a v2UploadFile builder instance to store the File Object and the filename
    .file(rep) //File Object
    .filename(namefile) //Filename
    .build(); //Build the v2UploadFile builder instance         
            
List<FilesUploadV2Request.UploadFile> listV2UploadFiles = new ArrayList<>();  //Create an arraylist called listV2UploadFiles
listV2UploadFiles.add(v2UploadFile); //Add the v2UploadFile instance to the listV2UploadFiles arraylist
       
FilesUploadV2Request f2Request = FilesUploadV2Request.builder()  //Create an f2Request instance of type builder    
    .uploadFiles(listV2UploadFiles) //Upload all the files defined in the arraylist called listV2UploadFiles
    .channel("-----------") // id of the channel
    .build(); //Build the f2Request instance
            
MethodsClient methodsClient = slack.methods(botUserOAuthAccessToken);  //Assign the botUserOAuthAccessToken to the methodsClient instance
FilesUploadV2Response f2Response = methodsClient.filesUploadV2(f2Request); //Make the request with the file information which will trigger a response f2Response
System.out.println(f2Response.toString()); //Print the f2response

